# Ionic Storage doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-storage

Setting doesn't work. Getting doesn't work.  I can't even get the driver name on iOS.  Calling "ready" doesn't work.  The calls just don't return.  The promises go unfulfilled.  It's like a void out there.

Ionic Storage on Android and Chrome work fine.

These are the plugins I have installed:

```
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.2.1 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.4 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-calendar 5.0.0 "Calendar"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.0 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-ionic 2.0.4 "IonicCordova"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
```

This is an idea of how I'm using it.  Keep it mind that my code works great on Android and in Chrome.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

this.platform.ready()
.then(()=>{
this.storage.ready()
.then(() => {
this.storage.get(name)
.then((value)=>{
```

I am also using catches to catch errors, but there aren't any.  It just dies.  "storage.ready" doesn't even return.

In my app.module.ts, I have these lines in the right places:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
```

Any ideas?  My head hurts from banging it against the wall.

Comment: Did you figure what was that? did you try using different driver (not sqlite)?

Comment: After trying lots of things, I finally gave up and used good old fashioned JavaScript localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Ive come across similar issues. To test whats going on in your .ts

```
      this.storageEngine = localStorage.storage.driver;
```

And then in your HTML file

```
        {{ storageEngine }}
```

What I suspect the issue is, its trying to use indexeddb, use sqlite on mobile devices to prevent garbage collection from wiping your data.

Step 1:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
```

Step 2: app.module.ts

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: '__yourapp-localstorage',
     driverOrder: ['sqlite','indexeddb', 'websql']
}),
```